# Handle already paginated data with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have already paginated data in the backend/server. I went through the docs of `<v-data-table>` but could not grasp the things there. Since I am using `vuex` and my data will be stored in `state`. Now how to combine them with, `<v-data-table>`.

`resident.js`:

```
export default {
  state : {
    residents: [],
  },
   mutations: {
    set_residents (state, residents) {
        state.residents = residents
    },
   },
   getters: {
    allResidents (state) {
        return state.residents
    },
   },
    actions: {
    get_resident_list (context, page) {
        let page = page.page || this.state.pagination.page;
        let count = page.count || this.state.pagination.count;
        return residentApi.getResidents(page, count) 
            .then(residents => {
                context.commit('set_residents', residents)
                return residents
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return Promise.reject(error)
            })
      },
    },
```

On ResidentList.vue file :

```
import { mapGetters,  mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
        residents: '',
        headers: ....,
    }
  },
  computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
        'allResidents',
    ]),
  },
  created() {
    this.get_resident_list(),
    this.residents = this.allResidents;
},
methods: {
    ...mapActions([
        'get_resident_list',
        'refresh_resident_list'
    ]),
 },
 watch: {
   allResidents() {
     this.residents = this.allResidents;
   }
 }
}
```

Now with this form of implementation, how do I use `vuetify's <v-data-table>` for pagination with paginated data?

Comment: Did you tried this one?
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#paginate-and-sort-server-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `:options.sync="options"` on `vuetify's <v-data-table>` and take an watcher on `options` as you want.
ref# https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#paginate-and-sort-server-side

Other way, you can just pass the page no to props as `:page="5"`

and handle by `@update:page="updatePagination"`

control the function from your vue methods,

```
updatePagination (pagination) {
    console.log('update:pagination', pagination)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Another question, in my api I can pass query `pageNumber` and number Of Item on page as `count`, does that `:page="5"` solve it ? So I can pass in API as `axios.get('/residents/?page='+page + '&count='+count)`

Comment: can you clarify more? I didn't get actually.

Comment: `axios.get('/residents/?page='+page + '&count='+count)` this is my api with pagination to call, how do  pass the page and count argument  ?

Comment: what i understand, you want to set and get count also on `v-data-table`. am i right?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to set count and get the data of length equals to count

Comment: use `:items-per-page="5"` to set and `@update:items-per-page="getItemPerPage"` to handle your change.